# A perfect riddle

Tags: riddle

> I consist of 1 and 3 
>   depending on how you see me
>
> 7 might be lucky 
>   but I am the youngest of all the perfects
>
> Turn me around 
>   and I become prey for the Irish
>
> Take off my top 
>   and I am nothing
>
> Take off my bottom 
>   and I am a well-rounded fellow

What am I, a perfect answer I am?

Answer (score 6):

Answer:

> 6

I consist of 1 and 3
depending on how you see me

> $6 = 3 +1+1+1$ (one 3 and three 1s)

7 might be lucky
but I am the youngest of all the perfects

> 6 is the smallest [perfect number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number)

Turn me around
and I become prey for the Irish

> still thinking about this one.

Take off my top
and I am nothing

> remove the top part of the 6 and you end up with 0 (zero or an empty space).

Take off my bottom
and I am a well-rounded fellow

> remove the bottom part of a 6 and it looks like rainbow

Comment: Nice answer but you got the last three clues wrong

Comment: Technically I got 2 wrong and skipped one. I'm working on them.

Comment: The Irish clue would be a snake.  ( My guess anyway )

Comment: turning it around it looks like number 9 maybe?

Comment: @PythonMaster Surely, take off my top and end up with nothing, means 6 becomes 0?

Comment: @user230452 that's what I said...apparently I'm wrong

Comment: @PythonMaster. How about now. Did I get the last clue right?

Comment: SIX...take the first two letters out of it and you have remaining X, which looks like cross. Similarly, take the last two letters out of it and you have remaining S, which looks well rounded.

Answer (score 0):

> A rainbow?

There are 7 colours in a rainbow, turn around and you'd have the pot of gold. May be well off here!

Comment: I'm not convinced this covers all the clues.

Answer (score 0):

Complementing/correcting a part of Marius answer:

Take off my bottom and I am a well-rounded fellow

> remove the bottom part and it becomes a circular paraboloid

Comment: Close... but no cigar

Answer (score 0):

> 8

```
I consist of 1 and 3
depending on how you see me
```

> a 1 and 3 next to each other make an 8 - especially on a digital clock, for example

```
7 might be lucky
but I am the youngest of all the perfects
```

> perfectly symmetrical up/down, right/left

```
Turn me around
and I become prey for the Irish
```

> still working on this one, but I think it has to do with the similarities to a snake, which the Irish captured

```
Take off my top
and I am nothing
```

> remove the top half of an 8 and it's a 0

```
Take off my bottom
and I am a well-rounded fellow
```

> Take off the bottom half and the top half is still "well-rounded"